# log4j/log4net set the time stamp to eastern time zone

Tags: log4j, log4net

I have an app that runs on azure. Azure uses UTC time for their date related stuff so all the log entries have "incorrect" times.

How can I change the log4net config file so the timestamps get recorded as eastern time zone?

My current pattern

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="[%date{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffzzz}] [%5level] (%identity-%username) %message%newline" />
  </layout>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. In what way are the log times "incorrect"? [The documentation for `%date`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) says _"Used to output the date of the logging event in the local time zone. To output the date in universal time use the %utcdate pattern."_ but you cannot make it output in a specific time zone. You could pass the time you want to log as a GlobalContext parameter, though, in which case you have full control over it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the timezone to your conversionPattern, for example:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="[%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffzzz}{GMT}] [%5level] (%identity-%username) %message%newline" />
  </layout>
```

You can check the layout [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html)

Comment: I don't think this works for version 2.0.8 in Nuget.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work.